# Ionic 3 Infinite Scroll fire event only fire once

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, infinite-scroll, viewchild

I am doing an app in **Ionic 3** and using [infiniteScroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) inside a  and . I see common issues in **github** and even here in **SO**. But most of it has no **solution**.

The problem is when the page is loaded and render all the data that is paginated from the **backend** when I get an **API** request. Now I had a `infiniteScroll event` when I scroll to the bottom part of my page. But the problem is that it only **trigger once** and load my data. If I want to load a new one I have to go back at the top of the content and go down again to load some data.

Here is my code in my **typescript file** below:

I used a [viewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for **Scroll** `native element` of **Ionic** inside my `<ion-slide>`

Here is the structure of my **html** below:

```
<ion-slide *ngIf="!preloader">
      <ion-scroll #scrollWeb scrollY="true">

<! -- Content Part for loop of an array with data from a server -->

<!-- Load more for following -->
        <ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="selectedSegment == 'first' && !pulling" (ionInfinite)="loadMorePost($event)">
          <ion-infinite-scroll-content
          loadingSpinner="crescent"
          loadingText="Loading more post..."
          >
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll>
        <small *ngIf="noMorePostToShowForExplore">No more post to show</small>
      </ion-scroll>
    </ion-slide>
```

And the **typescript**

```
loadMorePost(infiniteScroll? :any) {
    console.log('Async operation begun')
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.selectedSegment == 'first') this.loadMoreExplore()
        else this.loadMoreFollowing()
        infiniteScroll.complete(); 
      }, 1000);
  }
```

As I have said earlier about the `viewChild` I tried to trigger the y-axis scroll and only allow to refresh if it is at the most bottom part of the page. Which is still not working.

```
this.scrollWeb.addScrollEventListener((ev) => {
          if ((ev.target.offsetHeight + ev.target.scrollTop) >= ev.target.scrollHeight) {
            // this.loadMorePost(InfiniteScroll)
            console.log('Loading post')
          }
        })
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.